# How to display chart in deployed web app with apps scripts

Tags: google-apps-script

All I want to do is display a pie chart and a bar chart with data from my google sheet to an app deployed via apps script. I have tried every turtorial and looked through the docs exstensively. There seems to be way to much interlap between regular apps scripts and actual deployments using app scripts and I can't even get cell data to display in the browser despite going through the apps scripts turtorial from google.

I know javascript very well, but I am lost on displaying the sheet data to index html. If someone can show me an example of displaying a bar and pie chart with 3 fields each from sheet data I would greatly appreciate the boost to help me start understanding what direction I need to go in.

Comment: https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/reference

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgoogle-apps-script%5D+google.visualization

Answer (score 3):

### I was able to find the solution by loading html directly from the script

*this greatly simplified the process*

```js
function doGet() {
  // Open the spreadsheet by its ID and get the first sheet
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById('1rLj7ZIxM1VlgK7WwK8caIeWdI1oRdQqBndGrn_xl06Y').getSheets()[0];
  
  
// Specify the cell locations for the labels and their corresponding values for the pie chart
var pieDataCells = [
{labelCell: 'A2', valueCell: 'B2'},
{labelCell: 'A4', valueCell: 'B4'},
{labelCell: 'A6', valueCell: 'B6'}
];
// Specify the cell locations for the labels and their corresponding values for the bar chart
var barDataCells = [
{labelCell: 'A5', valueCell: 'B5'},
{labelCell: 'A3', valueCell: 'B3'}
];
.setTitle("Additional Data Points")
.build();
// Convert both charts to images
var pieChartBlob = pieChart.getAs('image/png');
var pieChartBlobData = Utilities.base64Encode(pieChartBlob.getBytes());
var barChartBlob = barChart.getAs('image/png');
var barChartBlobData = Utilities.base64Encode(barChartBlob.getBytes());

// get text from cell
var headerText= sheet.getRange('B1').getValue();
// Create and return the HTML output with both charts
var htmlOutput = HtmlService.createHtmlOutput('\
<html>\
<head>\
<title>Charts Display</title>\
</head>\
<body>\
<h2>Pie Chart</h2>\
<img src="data:image/png;base64,' + pieChartBlobData + '">\
<h2>Bar Chart</h2>\
<img src="data:image/png;base64,' + barChartBlobData + '">\
<h1>' + headerText + '</h1>\
</body>\
</html>')
.setWidth(450)
.setHeight(700); // Adjusted height to accommodate both charts
return htmlOutput;
}
```

Comment: pieDataCells and barDataCells does not seem to be used anywhere and what are .setTitle and .build() methods of.

Comment: @Cooper did you try the code?

Comment: What does that have to do with my question?